# Dll does not work properly on th another computer

Tags: dll, assembly, rebuild

I have program that uses a dll to make my device work. The driver for this device is installed on other computers.

My program works properly on my computer, but if I try to install it on another computer the dll no longer functions correctly (dll method can not find device).

But!, If I'm rebuild the program on the failing computer it works well.

What the reason of this behaviour?
Why it start work properly only after rebuilding ?

Comment: Lots of reasons, actually. If it were me, I'd start some deep troubleshooting, such as comparing a disassembly between both dlls.

Comment: This question broke my crystal ball.  Great, didn't plan to go shopping today.

Comment: @HansPassant what you need is a crystal ball repair chest http://img3.etsystatic.com/il_570xN.37943095.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It could be binding to a different set of dlls that it is dependant on one one computer but these could be different (but compatible) on the other target machine, a recompile would mean that this code then linked against a different library version and functioned.

This is however a best guess as the question is not reall answerable in its current form